# django multiple select in admin change-list

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Our product model can have multiple campaigns. Our customers change these campaigns frequently and generally on multiple products. So what we need right now seems that we need to show a multiple select widget on a change-list of Product model where our customers can easily change the campaigns.

Any idea on this? Maybe another way to achieve this kind of UI interaction?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

say you have a product model

```
class Product(models.Model):
  name=models.CharField(max_length=20)
  cost=models.DecimalField(max_length=10)
```

you can subclass the admin's Modeladmin to show a list display for the products  or you can do a custom modelform for the product which you can call in the product's admin

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms

class PropertyInline(admin.TabularInine):
   model=Property
   extra=1

class PropertyForm(admin.ModelAdmin):
   inlines=(PropertyInline,)
```

Comment: As I stated in the question, what I want to achieve is to chnage the change-list for the model. Inlining will customize the product add/edit page.